# Admin credentials right in the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm building a blog app and now I need to build the Admin backend. Since im going to be the only user, is it a bad idea to just have a code snippet in my controller that says:

```
if params[:username] == myusername && params[:password] == mypassword
```

For the admin log in?

Could someone potentially get into my controller.rb file and get that info out?

There are no other users or admins on the site so placing a table in my DB seems redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recommend to put the credentials into the controller. This is simply the wrong place. You should at least put them into a config file. You should instead think about using [Basic-Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) if you just want to keep random visitors away from an admin area.

If you would like to know more about how simple it is to integrate authentication the Rails way, check out this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

Comment: just typed the same answer, but you was the first :) +1 of course. Also, do not forget to put file with credentials into `.gitignore`